# AngularJS - on click event not working with ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'd like to count something after the button will be pressed. I think everything is okay, but it doesn't work. 
Here is the code for You:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/style.css">
    <title>AngularJS Równanie Liniowe</title>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
            $scope.y = $scope.a*$scope.x+$scope.b;
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="d1" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <form class="f1">
        <label for="x"> x: </label>
        <input ng-model="x" class="i1" type="number" name="x">
        <br>
        <label for="b"> b: </label>
        <input ng-model="b" class="i2" type="number" name="b">
        <br>
        <label for="a"> a: </label>
        <input ng-model="a" class="i3" type="number" name="a">
        <br>
        <input class="btn" type="submit"class="button" value="Wykonaj" ng-click="function">
    </form>
    {{$scope.y}}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use `ng-click = "yourfunction()"`.

Answer (score 0):

**1st Method**

Change your JS code:

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.calc = function() {
       $scope.y = $scope.a*$scope.x+$scope.b;
   }
});
```

And change your button:

```
<input class="btn" type="submit"class="button" value="Wykonaj" ng-click="calc()">
```

We defined a `calc()` function and wrapped your calculation code in it and then calling the same function with `ng-click="calc()"`

**2nd Method**

Or, you can remove the `ng-click="calc()"` from the button and instead add it to your form:

```
<form ng-submit="calc()"></form>
```

Since clicking the button will already submit the form.

**3rd Method**

You don't need a bit of Javascript here:

In place of `{{$scope.y}}`, just write `{{a * x + b}}`

Comment: Doesn't work yet :/. Both methods what u have wrote.

Comment: You have one more mistake... change {{$scope.y}}  for  {{y}}  as you don't need to reference $scope on the template

Comment: Can you add a console in the `calc` method.

Comment: Vi100 were right. It was this mistake. Now everything works fine. Thanks guys for help :3

Answer (score 0):

```
<http://plnkr.co/edit/X85NfM0TAdPa6uOGBde6?p=preview>?
```

Hai check the above link, i hope it will help you. Please check and let me know incase if u face any issue